# React Native one to one conversation using socket.io

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io, sequelize.js

i currently have a react native app with nodejs express Sequelize as my backend and postgres as my database.

So, on my posts screen next to each post, i have a text input and a button where the current user can send the user of the post an initial message. Once the button is pressed, a conversation between these 2 users about this post is created in my database and stored in my conversation table and an entry of the message sent is also stored in my messages table.

I have implemented bidirectional communication between these 2 users. But my problem is i need to refresh the app in order to show the user current user the sent message and to show the receiving user the received message.

I have been researching for a while now and trying to understand how to implement this feature using socket.io but could not get anywhere.

Client Side

Here is my Chat Screen

```
 function ChatScreen({route,navigation}) {

 const message = route.params.message;
 const [messages, setMessages] = useState(message.Messages);
 const [text, setText] = useState('');
 const { user } = useAuth();
 const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);


 useEffect(() => {
 const newsocket =io.connect(socketurl)
setMessages(messages);
newsocket.on('connection', msg => {
    console.log('i have joined')
    setMessages(messages=>messages.concat(msg))
    setSocket(newsocket)
 })
 return()=>newsocket.close;
 }, []);

const updateText=(text)=>{
setText(text);
}

  const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {
  console.log("sent")
messagesApi.sendMessage({ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
setText("")

socket.emit('message', { to: (user.id===route.params.message.user1 ? 
route.params.message.user2 : route.params.message.user1), from: 
user.id, message,ConversationId });
};

return(

<Text>{user.id === message.Recipient.id ? 
message.Creator.name:message.Recipient.name}</Text>

    <KeyboardAvoidingView 
    style={{
        display: "flex",
        flex: 1,
      }}
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 25 : 0}
    >

<FlatList
    inverted
    data={message.Messages}
    keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({item,index})=>(
        <MessageBubble
        text={item.message}
        mine={item.senderId !== user.id}
        />
    )}/>

    <View style={styles.messageBoxContainer}>
        <TextInput 
        style={styles.messageBox} 
        placeholder="Message..." 
        multiline
        clearButtonMode="while-editing"
        onChangeText={updateText} 
        value={text} 
        autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSend}>
            <Text style={styles.send}>Send</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
)
```

Server Side

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const socketio = require("socket.io")
const server=http.createServer(app);
const io =socketio(server)

io.on("connection", socket => {
 socket.on('message', (data) => {
  socket.join(data.ConversationId);
  io.sockets.in(data.to).emit('send_message', { message: data.message, 
  to: data.to });
});
});

const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");
server.listen(port, function () {
console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Currently when i send a message, the message gets stored in my database but my chat does not update instantly (ie. not live), i need to refresh my app and the messages appear.

Can someone please help me and check if the implementation of socket i currently have is correct and if so, how do i render my flatlist instantly?

*UPDATE*

i think something is wrong in my useEffect, because when i open the chat i am not getting "i have joined" in the console:

```
useEffect(() => {
setMessages(messages);
socket.on('connect', msg => {
    console.log('i have joined')
    setMessages(messages=>messages.concat(msg))
 })
 }, []);
```

Comment: Both users must send/emmit events to the same port. 

In Front End Define a Server Socket Port and on User Login, they send an event to that socket for a new entry. Now when the user starts a conversation it creates a new entry again that includes another user id.

I used socket for a Notification.

Comment: @VinitBhavsar do you have an example of how to use sockets because this is my first using them?

Comment: I don't have any experience on server side setup for socket, all we do on front end side is 
const socket = io("socket port address");

Emit Event Like This
socket.emit("send_request",data);
Socket Event Listner
socket.on("get_request", () => {})

Comment: So when ever send_request is called, get_request got updates of that

Comment: So, where exactly should i create my socket?

Comment: U have to define socket (master) on both side server and client

Comment: @VinitBhavsar thank you for trying to help, but unfortunately i am still new to sockets and have very little understanding of sockets so please bare with me. On server side, should i define my socket in index.js or inside the specific route. On client side, should i define my socket inside chat.js or App.js?

Answer (score 0):

Your currently creating a new connection on every state change.. `const socket =io.connect(socketurl)`

You have a useEffect callback and that would be the logical place to put your connection logic, currently your only listening once for a connection, but creating multiple connections, so your 'connection' event is never called on these new connections.  But you only want to connect once anyway, so we just need to put the connection logic also inside the useEffect, not just the connection event.

Because connecting to a socket is async, you will want to wait for the connection before rendering. So what we could do is store the socket in state, and when we get a connection set socket state, this will fire a re-render with a now valid socket.

eg.

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
...
useEffect(() => {
   const socket = io.connect(socketurl)
   setMessages(messages);
   newsocket.on('connect', msg => { //connect not connection
      console.log('i have joined')
      setMessages(messages=>messages.concat(msg));
      setSocket(newSocket);
   });
   //might make sense to close the socket too, 
   //otherwise a memory leak. 
   return () => newSocket.close();
}, [route, navigation]); 


if (!socket) {
  //we don't have a socket yet,
  return "loading..";
} else {
  // we have a socket, 
  const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {...
  ....
  // now render..
  return (
    <Text>{.........
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. i have followed the exact same code you have provided and it is not working. i am still not getting 'i have joined' in the console when i press on a chat. Also, is my socket logic on server side correct?

Comment: I keep getting TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating socket.emit)

Comment: @kd12345  Make sure anything you need the socket for is used after the bit I've put `//we have a socket`, because then socket can't be null.

Comment: yes i put my entire onSend function there but doing so i cannot access it in the TouchableOpacity onPress at the bottom of my return function

Comment: @kd12345  If you have done what I've shown, then TouchableOpacity will be in scope, there is something you have not done correctly.  Maybe update you original question code showing what you currently have..

Comment: Do you want me to put entire return() ie. with Flatlist and everything inside else statement? I thought you meant just the onSend function.

Comment: @kd12345  Yes,.  everything in the else part is were socket is valid.  So onSend the return of your JSX all wants to be in the else.

Comment: but now i am getting Error Text strings must be rendered within <Text> component. this occurs at the if(!socket) return "loading..", also what do you mean by socket is valid?

Comment: I don't use React Native, so I assume you will want to do what it says and do -> `return <Text>Loading</Text>`

Comment: I did that and got an empty page

Comment: @kd12345   Actually just looked again at your socket logic, yes, it doesn't look correct,.. Give us a tick I'll update..

Comment: @kd12345 Looking on socket.io, for client it's `on('connect')` not `on('connection')`..

Comment: And also i server side i change from connection to connect?

Comment: @kd12345  No, I think server side is still connection,  Server accepts multiple connections, so that's maybe why they name it that way..   Fingers crossed, you should now get the `i have joined` message.

Comment: Yes now socket is working i am getting 'i have joined' in console but my Flatlist does not update as soon as a message gets sent

Comment: @kd12345  Great stuff, ..  Might be best closing this one for now, and make another question for the FlatList updating, otherwise this thread is going to get  messy.. :)

Comment: Thank you alot Keith, you just saved my life. its been weeks i have been trying to understand sockets. Does this mean my 2 users are connected to the same room and can exchange live messages?

Comment: @kd12345   setSocket is used to set the state of socket, if it wasn't called socket would always be null.

Answer (score 0):

Socket Index.js

```
    /** Socket.io server listens to our app **/
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
    
    
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    /** On User Log In **/
    socket.on('login', function (data) {
            console.log('user joined >>', data)
            userList.addUser(data, socket);
        });

    // Example Event //
    socket.on('get_online_friends', userId => {
    //Get List Data And Then //
    let data = [UserList];
    socket.emit('send_online_friend', data);
    }
    )
    // On Logout //
     socket.on('disconnect', function (reason) {
            var offlineId = userList.removeUser(socket)
    );
    
    }
```

user_list.js

```
    var userList = {};
    module.exports = userList;
    
    var userData = [];
    var userSocData = {};
    
    userList.user = userData;
    userList.userSoc = userSocData;
    
    userList.getUserList = function () {
        return userSocData;
    };
    
    userList.addUser = function (user, client) {
        userSocData[user] = {
            socketId: client.id
        }
    };
    
    userList.setReceiverId = function (user, client) {
        var index = userData.findIndex(x => x.user_id == user['user_id']);
        if (index !== -1) {
            userData[index]['receiver_id'] = user['receiver_id'];
        }
        userSocData[user['user_id']] = {
            socket: client.id
        };
    };
    
    
    userList.removeUser = function (client) {
        for (const property in userSocData) {
            if (client.id === userSocData[property].socketId) {
                var userID = property;
                delete userSocData[property]
            }
        }
        return userID;
    };
```

Front End

```
    ***
    socket.emit("get_request", userData.user_id);
            socket.on("get_request_data", function (data) {
              if (data.status) {
                self.setState({ onlineFriends: data.data });
              }
            });
    ***
```

Comment: This is how I setup socket on the server side

Comment: hi, i have updated my question with my new code if you can please have a look.

Comment: Do i need to check if both users are in socket?

Comment: Sorry Vinit, i am still new with sockets so please bare with me. i have this in my server side socket.on('message', (data) => {
  socket.join(data.ConversationId);
  io.sockets.in(data.to).emit('send_message', { message: data.message, 
  to: data.to });
});

Comment: ok thank you, currently when the current user sends a message to another user, it is working the message gets sent to the correct user in the correct conversation. my problem is it is not rendering live i need to refresh my app in order for both users to see the message

Comment: Do you want to start a discussion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226051/discussion-between-kd12345-and-vinit-bhavsar).